# How to save passed value between two functions(callbacks) after closing the GUI?

Tags: matlab, function, user-interface, callback

I need to use output from first function as input to second function (callback). This is not a problem if I don't close the GUI but I want to use first callback, save value, close GUI and then open GUI again and use that value in second function. I hope you guys understand.

I tried to use CloseRequestFcn and OpeningFcn with setappdata/getappdata or save/load but either this can't be done or I'm doing something wrong.

I had few different errors like "Reference to non-existent field " or similar but still stuck.

Comment: Can you change your GUI to allow input values? This way, in your second call you could do something like `MyGUI( valueFromFirstGUIRun );` and then use that value in the opening function.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1. Use **global variables**: Declare a variable as global by using `global`. Write to this variable when you push the "Save" button and/or close the GUI. Then read from the global when you open the GUI and/or push a "Load" button.
2. Use a **file**: Use the `save` and `load` functions to store and retrieve Matlab variables to a file. Consult the Matlab documentation on how to store only specific variables.

**Global variable example:**

```
global testvar

if isempty(testvar)
    testvar = 0;
end

disp(datestr(now))
disp(testvar)

testvar = testvar + 1;
```

**File example:**

```
if exist('testfile.mat', 'file')
    load('testfile', 'testvar')
else
    testvar = 0;
end

disp(datestr(now))
disp(testvar)

testvar = testvar + 1;

save('testfile', 'testvar')
```